# Errors received in import on MAGMI

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

I am using Magmi to import all my products, I get the following errors. Can someone suggest a fix or what is causing it:

plugin;Magmi_CSVDataSource;warning:CSV Datasource v1.3 - warning: line 3 , wrong column number : 122 found over 118, line skipped

error:No sku info found for record #10

error:No sku info found for record #11

error:No sku info found for record #18

error:No sku info found for record #19

error:No sku info found for record #21

error:No sku info found for record #22

plugin;Magmi_CSVDataSource;warning:CSV Datasource v1.3 - warning: line 28 , wrong column number : 20 found over 118, line skipped

plugin;Magmi_CSVDataSource;warning:CSV Datasource v1.3 - warning: line 29 , wrong column number : 100 found over 118, line skipped

plugin;Magmi_CSVDataSource;warning:CSV Datasource v1.3 - warning: line 30 , wrong column number : 119 found over 118, line skipped

plugin;Magmi_CSVDataSource;warning:CSV Datasource v1.3 - warning: line 31 , wrong column number : 119 found over 118, line skipped

plugin;Magmi_CSVDataSource;warning:CSV Datasource v1.3 - warning: line 33 , wrong column number : 119 found over 118, line skipped

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems obviously that your input data is really malformed.

wrong column number found : X over Y, it seems that your csv had no correct enclosures set.

Sample case for "X>Y" (here 122 over 118):

```
column1,column2,column3  <= header , 1st line of CSV , 3 columns for sample
value1,value2,value3 <= this is ok
value1b with comma, continued, value2b, value 3b <= this cannot work 
"value1 with comma, continued",value2b,value 3b <= this is correct
```

Sample case for "X<Y" (here 10 over 118):

```
column1,column2,column3 <= header , 1st line of CSV , 3 columns for sample
value1b,value2b,value3b <= this is ok
value1c,value3c <= does not work, 2 values for 3 declared columns
```

For case "X<Y" , magmi has an option "malformed CSV" but beware, it will assume 1st column,1st value matching.so only ignoring last declared columns as undefined.

Which in the second sample i gave would assign "value3c" for "column2".

Another guess i could make is that you are not using the right CSV format for magmi but the "import/export" format of magento which is declared as not supported . (this is even written in bold in the UI !!!)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I fixed it by replacing the "," separator by ";" and it worked.